# Сomplement of the set of numbers of the form $ 4mn - m - n$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, prime-numbers, modular-forms, pythagorean-triples

Numbers of the form $4mn-m-n$ where $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ are

$$
A=\{2, 5, 8, 11, 12, 14, 17, 19, 20, 23, 26, 29, 30, 32, 33, 35, \ldots\}
$$
The set complement of the above set is
$$
B=\{1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10, 13, 15, 16, 18, 21, 22, 24, 25, 27, 28,\ldots\}
$$
Is it possible to write the set $B$ with some polynomial in one or more variables like the set $A$?
If not, is it possible to write $B$ as union of some subsets $B_i$ where each $B_i$ can be written with some polynomials with one or more variables?

thanks.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A094178

Comment: This was the thing done by Euler. kawa almost fully described the sets.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my thoughts.

Let us characterize $A=\{4mn-m-n:m,n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\}$ more precisely.

Note that, $k\in A \Leftrightarrow 4k+1=(4m-1)(4n-1)$ for some positive integers $m,n$. Since $m,n$ are positive we deduce this holds if and only if $k$ is such that $4k+1$ has a prime divisor of form $4\ell+3$ (if not, and all prime divisors of this number are of form $4\ell+1$ then such a representation is  clearly impossible). Thus, $k\in A$ if and only if $4k+1$ has a prime divisor of form $4\ell+3$.

There is also the following observation. If you allow $m,n$ to be integers, as opposed to positive numbers, then you can actually show $k\in A$ for every $k$. Indeed, do the same trick as above, and if $4k+1$ does not have a prime divisor of this form, then set $p\mid 4k+1$ a prime, let $4m-1=-p$ and $4n-1=\frac{4k+1}{p}$. Clearly, this system has a solution $(m,n)$ in integers.